# Is there a corpus of Arabic text that doesn't include quotations of the Quran?

Tags: corpora, arabic, resource-request

I want to search such a corpus to determine the commonality or in other terms the frequency of use of the word Quran القرآن in comparison to The Generous Quran القرآن الكريم. But the condition is that this use is by people directly, not embedded in quotes from the Quran itself.

What I want to do is to find out how people refer to the religious text, do they mostly use the title on the cover? Or do they use the word القرآن only.

Comment: Does the phrase القرآن الكريم (with article) occur anywhere in the Qur'an?

Comment: No it doesn't. What I want to do is to find out how people refer to the religious text, do they mostly use the title on the cover? Or do they use the word القرآن with out الكريم more often. This will help determine the title to be used for the article on the Qur'an in the Arabic Wikipedia.

Comment: In that case I really do not understand why you need to exclude Qur'an-quoting texts from your corpus.

Comment: I want to see the frequency in people's own usage, not in the Qur'an itself.

Comment: interesting question, but there's a problem: which language?  Arabic?  Malay? Englisg? etc.

Comment: different cultures will probably do this differently, for cultural/linguistic reasons that have little to do with religion.

Comment: PS. The Quran does not have a "cover". A  mushaf, does, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Since there are only so many sentences in the Qur'an itself, it ought to be easy enough to excise them from a corpus as it's being massaged -- or to mark and ignore them when they turn up in searches.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/eric/latifa/arabic_corpora.htm) is a list of Arabic corpora, with notes about their origins. While I doubt if any of them *specifically* exclude Quranic quotations, many of them will be predominantly non-Quranic.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.copticchurch.net/cgibin/bible/) text in Arabic almost certainly doesn't have any quotes from the Qur'an, also [here](http://folk.uio.no/amundbjo/grar/interpretatio/about.php). If these don't satisfy your criteria, you might want to clarify what kind of corpus and what kind of Arabic you have in mind.

Comment: Aristotle text is not useful I am afraid, I need a considerably large (many resources) general corpus, with the text being put in the modern times and old.